# Jsoup.connect() working with Java, not with Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I've tried the `Jsoup.connect()` example given on the Jsoup website and it works fine in Java.

For some reason, I can't make it work in Android Projects (Eclipse) even though I allow the Internet access permission in my `AndroidManifest`. The Jsoup library is installed correctly and I can work with `Jsoup.parse()` without any issues. Here's a few line of codes of what works in Java and also the permission in `AndroidManifest`.

**Java**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.ca/").get();
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.print(title);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
```

When I try to run it, it crashes and the log says:

```
01-09 20:19:30.560: E/AndroidRuntime(26839): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.mrdroidinator.com/com.mrdroidinator.com.Parselhjmq}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: 01-09 20:19:30.560: E/AndroidRuntime(26839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mrdroidinator.com/com.mrdroidinator.com.Parselhjmq}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Nobody ever had this issue? I was also able to connect to the Yahoo! API (OAuth) via Java but it does not work within the android application in Eclipse. I guess these problems are related?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by chance?  Maybe the proxy isn't set for your Android project?

Comment: it's easier now, see the sample recipe code here https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AccessHeaders.java

Answer (score 16):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

The problem is that you are performing a network operation on the main thread, which is prohibited in API level 11+. This is because if you do it the UI is "frozen" until the document finishes downloading, so it is needed to perform such operations on a different thread, which doesn't affect UI perfomance.

This is how you start a new thread:

```
Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    Document doc;
    try {
      doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.ca/").get();
      String title = doc.title();
          System.out.print(title);
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};
downloadThread.start();
```