# Android: Where to find solution to this LogCat error?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat

When my app stats up, i'm getting this error as shows below (not every time, just every now and then). Is there anyone that can tell me where i can search the problem of this error? I don't even know which part of my code is causing the nulpointerexception error.

The app is showing a crash, saying the app stopped, but it's still moving on the the menu..

```
11-14 15:16:13.972: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:15.424: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:17.566: W/InputEventReceiver(23147): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
11-14 15:16:18.597: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:20.148: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:23.041: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:25.684: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:28.156: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:28.877: W/InputEventReceiver(23147): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
11-14 15:16:32.430: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:33.622: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:39.848: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:41.259: W/InputEventReceiver(23147): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
11-14 15:16:41.639: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:16:43.651: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:17:46.014: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:17:49.617: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:17:49.617: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:17:49.617: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:17:51.389: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:17:51.389: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:17:54.572: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:17:55.803: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:17:55.803: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:17:55.803: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:17:57.955: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:17:57.955: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:17:59.147: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:18:00.550: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:18:02.461: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:18:05.184: D/AbsListView(23147): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-14 15:18:05.244: W/ResourceType(23147): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
11-14 15:18:05.444: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:18:05.444: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:18:10.479: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:18:10.479: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:18:11.540: D/dalvikvm(23147): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1166K, 15% free 14468K/16839K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 58ms
11-14 15:18:11.540: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.540: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)*b:a88
11-14 15:18:11.540: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.550: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(de.+8
11-14 15:18:11.550: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.550: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)*8fc:(
11-14 15:18:11.550: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.550: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(**:-8
11-14 15:18:11.560: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.570: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,*ec.*8(
11-14 15:18:11.570: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.570: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(.*:d8
11-14 15:18:11.570: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.570: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)((c*d8
11-14 15:18:11.570: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.570: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(-be-(
11-14 15:18:11.570: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.570: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(-a-:8
11-14 15:18:11.580: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.580: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)**ba+(
11-14 15:18:11.580: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.580: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,*ed+)f(
11-14 15:18:11.580: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.580: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(8(+*(
11-14 15:18:11.580: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.580: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(.b*c8
11-14 15:18:11.590: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.590: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)*./,:(
11-14 15:18:11.590: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.590: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(b:eb(
11-14 15:18:11.590: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.590: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(c**b(
11-14 15:18:11.590: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.590: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(8:a((
11-14 15:18:11.600: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.600: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(::a.8
11-14 15:18:11.600: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.600: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)(dd,88
11-14 15:18:11.600: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.600: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)*::/a(
11-14 15:18:11.600: D/AbsListView(23147): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-14 15:18:11.610: I/MotionRecognitionManager(23147):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)*b):8(
11-14 15:18:11.840: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:18:11.840: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:18:13.452: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:18:13.452: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:18:13.452: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:18:16.695: W/Resources(23147): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f090042}
11-14 15:18:17.005: I/dalvikvm(23147): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
11-14 15:18:17.065: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:18:17.206: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:18:17.206: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23147): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-14 15:19:26.785: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:19:26.785: E/SpannableStringBuilder(23147): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4170)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:377)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:320)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:493)
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.emmtec"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" 
    tools:ignore="OldTargetApi"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emmtec.IntroScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emmtec.MenuScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emmtec.FirstScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first_screen"  
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emmtec.SecondScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emmtec.FinalScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_final_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emmtec.ThirdScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_third_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emmtec.CaptureSignature"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_capture_signature" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

The order of appearing should be: IntroScreen (splashscreen for 3 sec) - MenuScreen with options to go to other screens.

Introscreen.java:

```
public class IntroScreen extends Activity {

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 3000; 
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.emmtec.MESSAGE";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro_screen);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(IntroScreen.this,MenuScreen.class);
            mainIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "begin");
            IntroScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent); //start menu scherm
            IntroScreen.this.finish(); //stop intro scherm
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT); //na 3000 ms.
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any more `Caused by:`'s?

Comment: I'll post everything that happens before the error. @barwnikk the code is 8000 lines, I dont know what part to post.. You want to see the splashscreen or menuscreen maybe?

Comment: Wow. this is one file? I don't recommend to use all in one file 8000 lines.

Comment: haha no ;), i got about 25 classes, but i dont know where to seach the error.

Comment: I forgot to tell in first question: The app shows a crash message, but it is still moving on and the rest of the app is working fine

Comment: Your problem could be related to your Manifest... what did you set for the application name? Ex. <application android:name...> did you specify a custom class? That class is in the correct package? Please post your Manifest.

Comment: I suspect Eclipse plugin causes this ... Just tap CTRL+F11 and move along, next time it might not crash

Comment: @fasteque editted the post, now with manifest.

Comment: I've been getting the same error for awhile now but no luck on a solution. Anyway, [here is a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039017/android-app-application-cannot-be-instantiated-due-to-nullpointerexception) hasn't helped me yet but maybe you can find a similarity in yours

Comment: @codeMagic Yeah, I've seen that post too, it's kinda telling us that it's only happening when developing with Eclipse, and never for normal users.. Still i hoped someone really found an awnser to the problem;)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I would like to know exactly what the issue is also. [I had also found this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150899/runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application), I don't know if you've seen it but explains a little more (not much) but I so far have found the same thing that it only happens on devices 4.0 and newer.

Comment: could you please post at least the onCreate method for com.example.emmtec.IntroScreen activity? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399789/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application-android-app-applic

Comment: are you extending an `Application` class

Comment: @SathMK no.. only Activity class, should I?

Comment: is the app is working after the splash screen ??

Comment: @SathMK Yes, for the rest everything is working fine, it just shows that error message (app.... has stopped) once, but it doesn't actually stop, just moves on and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the problem in:

```
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:377)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:320)
11-14 15:21:28.947: E/AndroidRuntime(16132):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:493)
```

Maybe the parameter to initialize the Handler

Comment: Where would i fine that parameter?