# FATAL EXCEPTION: main error - Android development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, fatal-error

I am currently making an android app and am trying to resolve this issue. Whenever I compile my code and lode it onto the emulator, it initially loads up with these errors:

```
05-22 00:12:54.753: W/dalvikvm(1631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
05-22 00:12:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(1631):     ... 11 more
```

Then it kicks me out of the app with a force close but it boots back up soon after automatically and runs just fine. If I close the app and kill it, it doesn't force close or anything. Just when it initially boots up on the emulator. I was wondering what would be the reasoning for this. Here are the messages that pop up after it loads up the second time:

```
05-22 00:13:07.113: D/dalvikvm(1664): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 3% free 9110K/9347K, paused 61ms
05-22 00:13:07.165: I/dalvikvm-heap(1664): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.525MB for 3732496-byte allocation
05-22 00:13:07.263: D/dalvikvm(1664): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 12754K/12999K, paused 5ms+5ms
05-22 00:13:07.543: D/dalvikvm(1664): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 12755K/12999K, paused 37ms
05-22 00:13:07.573: I/dalvikvm-heap(1664): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.502MB for 2073616-byte allocation
05-22 00:13:07.753: D/dalvikvm(1664): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 14780K/15047K, paused 5ms+5ms
05-22 00:13:08.033: D/gralloc_goldfish(1664): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

I will supply you with any and all coding you guys need but unfortunately I do not know where this error would be at? I have many files inside of my program so I would rather not post all of them if at all possible.

Sorry that this question hasn't given much information, I just don't know what information to give to you (if that makes sense?) Please respond and tell me what information you would need and thank you for any and all of your help

### EDIT

here is my splash.java

```
package com.food;

import com.food.odu.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

//creating a splash effect so the company logo appears for a few seconds before the program
public class Splash extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);  //defined the reference id 'splash' in the splash.xml file

        Thread timer = new Thread(){    //creates a new timer for our splash effect
            public void run(){   //runs the splash program
                try{
                     sleep(5000);    //attempts to run the splash picture for 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
                   } catch(InterruptedException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();    //if that doesn't work, this line is debugging information
                      }finally{
                        Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.rhodes.jacob.COM.FOOD.ODUACTIVITY"); //creating an intent which is basically a reference to the Android Manifest
                        startActivity(openStartingPoint);                                               //file saying that when this intent is called, to go to the address at that name in the Android Manifest file
                      }
                  }

        };

        timer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }



}
```

---

and here is my oduActivity.java (my main, i suppose)

```
package com.food;


import com.food.odu.R;
//import com.food.odu.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class oduActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button Cafe1201, Legends, Rogers, Faculty;
    TextView display;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button Cafe1201 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cafe1201);
        Button Legends = (Button)findViewById(R.id.legends);
        Button Rogers = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rogers);
        Button Faculty = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fac_n_staff);

  //    Button Legal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.legal);
  //    Button Other = (Button)findViewById(R.id.other);
  //    Button About = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aboutUs);
        //Button Mainpage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_page);

        //Changes page to the cafe1201 page
        Cafe1201.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent whichCafe = new Intent(oduActivity.this,cafe1201.class);
                startActivity(whichCafe);

            }
        });


         //changes page to the legends page
          Legends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent whichCafe = new Intent(oduActivity.this,legends.class);
                    startActivity(whichCafe);

                }
            }); 


          //changes page to the rogers page
          Rogers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent whichCafe = new Intent(oduActivity.this,rogers.class);
                  startActivity(whichCafe);

              }
          }); 


          //changes page to the faculty page
          Faculty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent whichCafe = new Intent(oduActivity.this,faculty.class);
                  startActivity(whichCafe);

              }
          }); 


    }

    //Options menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
        blowUp.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.main_page:

            Intent whichOption = new Intent(oduActivity.this,oduActivity.class);
            startActivity(whichOption);
            break;
        case R.id.other:

            whichOption = new Intent(oduActivity.this,menu.class);
            startActivity(whichOption);
            break;
        case R.id.aboutUs:

            whichOption = new Intent(oduActivity.this,aboutUs.class);
            startActivity(whichOption);
            break;
        case R.id.legal:

            whichOption = new Intent(oduActivity.this,legal.class);
            startActivity(whichOption);
            break;

        }
        return false;
    }






     //   display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
  //  }
 }
```

Comment: and your code? sorry but without your code we can do anything...

Comment: You might try uninstalling the App from the emulator

Comment: did you delete the onCreate() method?. post some code. it looks like you just didn't instantiate something

Comment: Check out the top answer in this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150899/runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try this,

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this,ODUACTIVITY.class); //creating an intent which is basically a reference to the Android Manifest
                        startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Sorry for the late accepted answer though

Answer (score 1):

I see null pointer in here. You should set break point and try with another emulator...

Comment: What other emulator can I try it on?

Comment: I mean, you start new emulator with different Android version.