# Android Initial error in Emulator on Application Start

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am faced with this weird error. Whenever I start my application on my emulator, I get a message in the Emulator saying that **Unfortunately,Search has stopped**.

My LogCat also shows some error but after a few seconds, the application runs properly without any hassles.

But, every time I upload and install the application on the emulator I get this error.

I realise that it does not cause any trouble to the application as after the initial error, everything runs fine but still I would very much like to know the cause of such an error.

Here is what my LogCat displays.

```
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
07-08 13:47:38.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1931):     ... 11 more
```

Any idea what might be the cause ?

Comment: Did you try a different emulator?

Comment: Try deleting the old AVD and create a new one.

Comment: also try with clean Project and run again on new AVD

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried out in different systems on different emulators. But all of them were Android 4.0.3. Is my problem something specific to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you correctly declared the `android:name` attribute of your application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
2. See this answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10150899/844882) for an explanation on the `Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application` logcat error.

Comment: Yeah the name attribute of the application tag points to the activity which gets called when the application is started.

Comment: Anyway, read the explanation in the link you provided in your answer. I am able to identify the cause of the problem now. Thanks.

Comment: yup, glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 0):

Make an entry in androidManifest.xml with the application name

```
<application
        android:name=<name of the class that extends Application>
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```