# getResources returns null

Tags: java, android

We register a broadcast receiver to receive package installment or uninstallment event.

But some users report crash reports like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.kc.security.MoSecurityApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: getResources is null: dir - /data/app/com.cm.mg-1.apk, srcVal-1, srcVal-2
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:495)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: getResources is null: dir - /data/app/com.cm.mg-1.apk, srcVal-1, srcVal-2
at com.kc.security.b.ab.b(UpdateManager.java:69)
at com.kc.security.b.ab.a(UpdateManager.java:112)
at com.kc.security.MoSecurityApplication.onCreate(MoSecurityApplication.java:66)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:492)
... 11 more
```

> It is not easy to reappear this crash. We think a lot about this problem. We receive  a
>   uninstall event ,then the Application context Class called it's onCreate method, we do 
>   some initial works there , when we call getResouce(), it returns null .  When look deep 
>   inside the framework codes, we find that getReource locate resources file by sourceDir 
>   String in ApplicationInfo, and the String is "/data/app/com.cm.mg-1.apk"  > it's the original apk , and it is not exists anymore.

It maybe happens  when user update our application. In some way "/data/app/com.cm.mg-1.apk"   is allready deleted and replace by "/data/app/com.cm.mg-2.apk" any way, but the "sourceDir" String in ApplicationInfo is not update.

> I want to know what android does when doing a updating.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered a similar problem, check this out.

[RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150899/runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application/10158241#10158241)

I think this should answer this question, maybe because the Resources has been destroyed during this uninstall event.