# Android SharedPreferences Multiple values in Multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my android application I used sharedpreference to store values in two activites like in first activity to store the values of login. So once user logs in, his username and password is saved and he will be routed to calculation activity, where user needs to fill his  data inside several edittexts here I used second shared preference to store the edittext value. On pressing the show report button, user is directed to the next page that is daily prediction. So next time when user want to see the prediction, if he has logged in then he needs to skip the above said two activities and display the result. In my case I am able to achieve the login process correctly, but I used the second sharedpreference to store the edittext value the app is crashing. I am giving my code below.

first activity .. login activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            setContentView(R.layout.directcalc_xm);


            /*
             * Check if we successfully logged in before. 
             * If we did, redirect to calculation page
             */
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

                    if (settings.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged") && settings.getString("log", "").toString().equals("log")) 
                    {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(DirectCalculation.this, FullExplanationEntry.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                    } 


                    else
                    {
                        btn1 = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button1);
                        btn2 = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button2);

                        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent intent = new Intent(DirectCalculation.this, SignInActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        });

                        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent in = new Intent(DirectCalculation.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

second Activity .. calculation page

```
if(firstName.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Name should not be left blank.. Please enter your First Name and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }

        else if(lastName.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Last Name should not be left blank.. Please enter your Last Name and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }

        else if(callFirstName.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your First Name that is currently used and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }



        else
        {   


            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("log", "log");
            editor.commit();

            Intent i = new Intent(this, TabLayoutActivity.class);


            //Personal Year
            i.putExtra("name18",sum18 + "");
            //Personal Month
            i.putExtra("name19",sum19 + "");
            //Personal Dya
            i.putExtra("name20",sum20 + "");
            //Current Pinnacle
            i.putExtra("pin", pin + "");
            //Current Challenge
            i.putExtra("ch", ch + "");

            i.putExtra("yearstr", yearstr);
            i.putExtra("monthstr", monthstr);
            i.putExtra("daystr", daystr);
            startActivity(i);

}
}
```

logcat

```
01-17 08:37:30.800: D/Single Product Details(1267): {"product":[{"updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","pyno":"4","pdyno":"4","pmnno":"4","pdaynumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Day Number 4.","pmonthnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Month Number 4.","pyearnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Year Number 4.","created_at":"2013-11-28 01:16:49","rthoughtnumber":"This is the prediction for Relational Thought Number 4.","pid":"4","rthno":"4"}],"success":1}
01-17 08:37:31.380: D/Single Product Details(1267): {"product":[{"pinnacle":"This is the prediction for Pinnacle Number 6.","created_at":"2013-11-23 03:08:57","pid":"6","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","challenge":"This is the prediction for Challenge Number 6.","pinnum":"6","chnum":"6"}],"success":1}
01-17 08:37:31.461: I/Choreographer(1267): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-17 08:37:31.769: I/Choreographer(1267): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-17 08:37:32.130: I/Choreographer(1267): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-17 08:38:00.560: D/AndroidRuntime(1313): Shutting down VM
01-17 08:38:00.560: W/dalvikvm(1313): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
01-17 08:38:00.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1313):     ... 11 more
```

SignIn Activity

```
if(password.equals(storedPassword)) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                /*
                 * So login information is correct, 
                 * we will save the Preference data
                 * and redirect to the next activity. 
                 */
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                editor.commit();




                // the data is verified correct and the activity id redirecting to the user details entry page.

                Intent i = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,FullExplanationEntry.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
```

and when pressing button I need to go to third activity that is TabLayoutActivity

Comment: I don't see in this code where do you store this `edittext`.

Comment: And this error seems weird, can you post the full code

Comment: in second activity.. I stored the edittext values code

Comment: The only thing you store there is `editor.putString("log", "log")`.

Comment: Exactly where you got the error login activity or second activity

Comment: so what i need to do..?

Comment: Error I got from the second activity

Comment: I updated the code with sigin activity.. that is working fine

Comment: Did you make this app in some kind of app generator or something?

Comment: I dont know is it possible to use shared preference to save values in two different activities

Comment: No.. I did this code myown.. I got a code from other site and I made some changes for my use.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the code you've posted. Maybe in the `TabLayoutActivity.class`? You're sending there some values from the second Activity. It's hard to say because this error is strange.

Comment: Yeah it is possible to store value in share preference in any activity but name should be different, if you are same name in different activity latest value replaced the prev value.

Comment: so can u please check my names are corect..

Comment: I think my mistake is there... in second activity the app is not saving the value

Comment: After storing the values into preference check whether value stored or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on 4.0 right ? No fault of your part - see this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25869) and for a very nice explanation [RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150899/runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application/10158241#10158241)

Comment: So what I have to do for this

Comment: @user3180759:Did you read the links I posted ? Do you encounter this during your testing ? The exception is not thrown by your code - you can't do anything - read the links. Reinstall clean to solve