# Why does my app stop working?

Tags: android

I could find any error on my app, but it just working and crashed

```
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.handshake: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.handshake" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.handshake-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.handshake-1, /system/lib]]
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.handshake" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.handshake-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.handshake-1, /system/lib]]
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
03-11 13:55:40.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
```

What wrong with my application, below is my Android `Manifest`, can somebody help check, what does

```
Unable to instantiate application com.example.handshake: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.handshake" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.handshake-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.handshake-1, /system/lib]]
```

means?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.handshake"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="Handshake"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginSignupActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Welcome" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.handshake;


import com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Determine whether the current user is an anonymous user
        if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
            // If user is anonymous, send the user to LoginSignupActivity.class
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    LoginSignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            // If current user is NOT anonymous user
            // Get current user data from Parse.com
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null) {
                // Send logged in users to Welcome.class
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                // Send user to LoginSignupActivity.class
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        LoginSignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

mY PARSE APPLICATION.JAVA

```
package com.example.handshake;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import android.app.Application;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, "Gy6cJBwa0XJz3n08Oan7QPIZBFeimZjbGuu8ZK5T", "SMFf1m3jBj2HBtVm0Q0OoEpMhQC4oYgVoDn4hfT8");

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this
        // line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post your java code? also indicate how many java files are there in your project along with their names?

Comment: This Question was already asked here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150899/runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application

:)

Comment: i JUST ADD TWO OF MY jAVA FILE

Answer (score 0):

I just change my android Manifest and problem are solved, I change the name of the android name to "ParseApplication".........................................................................................................................................

```
<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginSignupActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Welcome" >
    </activity>
</application>
```