# Exception while testing my application on device by connecting divce with usb

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

It gives exception whenever app is installed and launched . And somtime it suddenly through **exception** and my gets **crashed**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4255)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:140)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:377)
>                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:320)
>                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:493)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4255) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:140) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Why this exception is thrown ? and how to handle it .I am new to android world

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150899/runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application/10158241#10158241

Comment: make sure your minSdk version is 15 or above.., if its 15 or above then no need to disable instant run

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Instant Run option in Android Studio.

Instant Run tries to do hot swapping of your code; this causes the application class to be moved.

To disable Instant Run Go to File --> Settings--> Build,Execution,Deployment -->Instant Run ---> uncheck "Enable instant run"

Comment: But instant runs is an important feature of android studio and it is really help full . Disabling it will really slow down my speed of practice and testing

Comment: @FaisalAhmed Agree. However, in its current state its really buggy. (in one of my apps it jumbled up the string resources while testing!. At other instances, it messes with Alert Dialogs, etc.)

Comment: Yes instant run is buggy as its in earlier stage so you should try disabling it to solve your problem